# Reindex Pages Library using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I want to reindex page library using powershell. I have try with c# code. Code is below.

```
void Main()
{
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://demosvr1/web1/"))
 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
 {    
  SPList docList = web.Lists["Documents"];
  object versionObj = docList.RootFolder.Properties["vti_searchversion"];
  int version = ((versionObj is int) ? ((int) versionObj) : 0); 

  docList.RootFolder.SetProperty("vti_searchversion", (version + 1));
  docList.Update();
 }
}
```

How to do that using powershell ?

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://demosvr1/web1/
$list = $w.Lists["Documents"]
$versionObj = $list.RootFolder.Properties["vti_searchversion"]
$list.RootFolder.SetProperty("vti_searchversion", ($versionObj + 1));  
$list.Update();
```

Comment: Hi,this script works fine and it is updating number but when i crawl search it will not display my library in manage catalog connection. If i manually reindex doc library and run search service than it is displaying. Do i missing something?