# Reindex search results (Content Search Web Part, 2013)

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, content-search-web-part

I will just leave this here, since it helped us a lot:

We have a [Content Search Web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163789%28v=office.15%29.aspx) with custom [Display Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138%28v=office.15%29.aspx) with link to edit item.
After user edit item, we want to refresh the search result, for example the item should be removed from the search result based on some criteria.

Answer (score 2):

What we did was to use this marvelous trick by @user1337886 and @damjan-tomic: [Reindex Pages Library using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87397/reindex-pages-library-using-powershell). Might be originating from something like http://blog.icsharp.net/2013/04/how-to-force-web-list-or-library-to-recrawl.html .
Just instead of using PowerShell or C# we did it using JSOM, which makes it a tiny bit different, and we triggered the code on modal close (from Display Template).

Here is the gist (without modal):

```
var listTitle = 'List title';
var folder = c.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle).get_rootFolder();
var properties = folder.get_properties();
c.load(folder);
c.load(properties);
c.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var version;
    try {
        version = properties.get_item('vti_searchversion');
    } catch (e) {
        version = 0;
    }

    properties.set_item('vti_searchversion', version + 1);
    folder.update();
    c.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
```