# Error while trying to ReIndex SPList using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

am trying to ReIndex a custom splist using powershell [ src link  :  [reindex-pages-lib](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87397/reindex-pages-library-using-powershell)

```
   add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction
      SilentlyContinue

      $SiteURL = "http://server001:28516/"
       $ListName =  "Risk and Issue Log Tracker"  
      $w = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
        $list = $w.Lists[$ListName]
        $versionObj = $list.RootFolder.Properties["vti_searchversion"]
        $list.RootFolder.SetProperty("vti_searchversion",
        ($versionObj + 1));  
         $list.Update();
```

but it throws me error:

> Some error occured. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

under what n whic  circumstances it will throw errors? when I tried with all the other docu libs and splists, i didnt get this error.

This is happening only for this list!

[image: LISTNAME-DEBUG]

Answer (score 3):

Open the list by browsing to it with your browser and compare the name of the list to the url.  Use what is in the url for $listName = "What is in the browser"

So if the browser says http://server001:28516/lists/what%20is%20list, you wouldnt use $listName = "What is in the browser" but instead you would use $listName = "What is list"

The reason for this is when a list gets created the name used is what is hard coded into the URL.  Then if business decides they don't like that name, then the name is changed, but the initial url remains.  This might be what happened here.

Hope this helps

See if $w.lists | ft title, nocrawl  shows that the list is marked to not allow indexing, if the nocrawl property is true.

Comment: i think, you are correct, they changed the name of list after creating the same.Lemme follow your suggestions n revert here. I think you are talking about the internal name of the list. its RILT , NOT THE  one i have mentioned in the $listname variable. But when i tried with the  RILT as $list name it throws another error:                                                          
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At E:\PoCSolutions\ReindexDocLibsNPD.ps1:13 char:1
+ $list.Update();

Comment: is RILT what shows in the browser?

Comment: Yes, this is the url : http://server001:28516/Lists/RILT/NewView.aspx

Comment: try stepping through you ps1.  run the line that get-spweb http://server001:28516/ and then instantiate that into the $w, then see what or if $w.lists returns for the RILT list.

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED the question with the screenshot. one more question, how will i come to know, the SPSLIST is corrupted?

Comment: My previous comment where I said try stepping through....- - actually that seems to spew out all the xml for the list, see if this returns the list name (get-spweb http://server001:28516/ ).lists | ft title    Maybe the list was marked to not be indexed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60653/discussion-between-stacy-and-samolpp).